# Why is span and form div not aligned in firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The following html&css works fine in chrome but on firefox it is not aligned

```
    <div class="btns">
    <div id="green">    
<span id="cls" class="btn btn-block btn-large btn-success disabled green_btn">Green</span>

    </div>
    <div id="red">
        <form class="button_to" >
            <div>
                <input class="btn btn-block btn-large btn-danger red_btn" type="submit" value="Red">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#cls:hover {
    background:black;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.btns {
    position: relative;
}
.num {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
#green, #red {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
    position: relative;
}
.green_btn, .red_btn {
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vYFf/)

I don't understand why they are not aligned in firefox but in chrome they are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**used to this**

Define your `#green, #red` **id** `vertical-align:top;`

```
#green, #red {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7vYFf/4/)**

More **[information about this](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/)**

Comment: Hi @NickGinanto More about this http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/

Answer (score 1):

You should use `float: left;` instead of `inline-block;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7vYFf/1/)

Note : Don't forget to clear your floats

Comment: that squishes them together, and it doesn't make it look like it is in chrome from my fiddle

Comment: @NickGinanto You can provide `margin-right` if you need spacing, and you should use `floats` for these purposes instead of `inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

you just add `float:left;` above `#red #green` see the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vYFf/2/).

```
#green, #red {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: sorry but that reverses the order and doesn't make it look like it is in chrome